# Breeze import with entity extended property of ko.observableArray() throwing error

Tags: breeze

Running into an error during import for entities extended with a `ko.observableArray()` property, vs. being extended as a simple array `[]` type in the constructor.

```
var customerCtor = function () {
    this.extendedProp = ko.observable(true);
    //this.extendedArray = ko.observableArray(); // causes error: Cannot write a value to a ko.computed unless you specify a 'write' option. If you wish to read the current value, don't pass any parameters.
    this.extendedArray = []; // this works just fine
  };
```

I created a test along-side the Breeze v1.3.6 DocCode: exportImportTests.js "stash entire cache locally and restore" as my starting point, and here is the new test:

```
test("w/extended Customer, stash entire cache locally and restore", 3, function () {
  var em1 = newEm();

  var store = em1.metadataStore;
  // extend Customer with observables 
  var customerCtor = function () {
    this.extendedProp = ko.observable(true);
    this.extendedArray = ko.observableArray(); // causes error: Cannot write a value to a ko.computed unless you specify a 'write' option. If you wish to read the current value, don't pass any parameters.
    //this.extendedArray = []; // but this will work just fine?
  };

  store.registerEntityTypeCtor("Customer", customerCtor);

  var expected = testData.primeTheCache(em1);
  // grab first Customer, push value onto extendedArray prop
  var custEntity = em1.getEntities(expected.customerType)[0];
  custEntity.extendedArray().push('some-value');  // even when defined as [], Breeze re-writes field as ko.observable

  var exportData = em1.exportEntities();

  var stashName = "stash_everything";
  window.localStorage.setItem(stashName, exportData);

  var importData = window.localStorage.getItem(stashName);
  var em2 = new EntityManager(); // virginal - so register ctor on this instance
  var store2 = em2.metadataStore;
  store2.registerEntityTypeCtor("Customer", customerCtor);
  em2.importEntities(importData);

  var entitiesInCache = em2.getEntities();
  var restoreCount = entitiesInCache.length;
  equal(restoreCount, expected.entityCount,
      "should have restored expected number of all entities");

  var restoredCustomer = em2.getEntities(expected.customerType)[0];
  ok(restoredCustomer.extendedProp(), 'extended property present');
  ok(restoredCustomer.extendedArray().length > 0, 'extended Array present and has data');
});
```

An `em2.importEntities(importData);` throws the error:

```
Error: Cannot write a value to a ko.computed unless you specify a 'write' option. If you wish to read the current value, don't pass any parameters.
at Error (<anonymous>)
at h [as extendedArray] (http://localhost:47595/Scripts/knockout-2.2.1.js:44:167)
at ctor.initializeEntityPrototype.proto.setProperty (http://localhost:47595/Scripts/breeze.debug.js:14634:31)
at updateTargetPropertyFromRaw (http://localhost:47595/Scripts/breeze.debug.js:13062:24)
at aspectName (http://localhost:47595/Scripts/breeze.debug.js:13025:13)
at Array.forEach (native)
at updateTargetFromRaw (http://localhost:47595/Scripts/breeze.debug.js:13023:19)
at em._inKeyFixup (http://localhost:47595/Scripts/breeze.debug.js:12601:17)
at Array.forEach (native)
at importEntityGroup (http://localhost:47595/Scripts/breeze.debug.js:12568:28)
```

As Breeze always rewrites constructor fields (in my case for KO), defining as `[]` works.  But not sure why this would happen when the property is pre-defined?

Anyone run into this, or have I missed a doc note somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

We'll look at it.

Yes, Breeze assumes every property added in a constructor is supposed to be rewritten per the prevailing "model library" which, in your case, is KO. Therefore, no surprise that the array becomes a ko.observableArray.

Moreover, because such a property is presumed to be under Breeze's jurisdiction, we have to tie it into Breeze observability and serialization mechanisms which means we re-write it as a Breeze-flavored observable array. Such an array is a computed.

Evidently there is some problem with the way we're doing this for a property which is "unmapped". We'll look at that.

N.B.: I am assuming (and your code confirms) that the array property, `extendedArray`, is an "unmapped property" in the Breeze sense. That should be fine.

**You should not mention mapped collection navigation properties in your constructor**. There is no valid reason to do so that I can think of. The main reason to mention a mapped property in the constructor is (a) to give it a default value or (b) make it available to a custom (unmapped) computed property. There is no reasonable alternative default value for a collection navigation property (empty is the default) and it would be rare/avoidable to include it in a computed.

Comment: Assumption is correct, `extendedArray` is showing as `isUnmapped:true` in a Breeze sense. Nothing about these extended properties were intended to be navigational - only for client-side specific data.  I'm trying to leverage breeze export/import for client-side tombstone functions - and as such want to define in the ctor vs. via a initializer.  Thank you for taking a look...

Comment: That bit of info helps. Sounds like a potential Breeze bug. We will look